# kendoui json fill datagrid

Tags: json, datagrid, kendo-ui

This works fine, filling grid:

```
  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
      data: [
        {'id': 1, 'name': 2, 'author': 3},
        {'id': 1, 'name': 2, 'author': 3},
        {'id': 1, 'name': 2, 'author': 3},
      ] ,
    },
```

but when I load list from getJSON:

```
  $.getJSON('/api/notes/', function(data) {
      dataSource = data.rows;
  });
```

Pointing `data` to `dataSource` array nothing is displayed :(

Comment: What is `dataSource` inside the `getJSON`. I'm afraid that your code is not complete enough for being able of helping. BTW: Did you check how `data` looks like? Does it really contain an `array` named `rows`?

Comment: JSON goes like:

{"total": 6, "rows": [{"id": "AA", "name": "Foo", "author": "Bar"}, ...

Answer (score 0):

If received data is in `data.rows`, you should do:

```
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data = data.rows;
```

But, why do you not use [`transport.read`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#transportread-objectstringfunction) in the `grid.dataSource` for loading data instead of using `getJSON`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the **[data](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#data)** method of the dataSource.

e.g.

```
$.getJSON('/api/notes/', function(data) {
  dataSource.data(data.rows);
```

});

Comment: I'm doing this way:var myjson;

$.getJSON('/api/notes/', function(data) { 
  console.log(data);
  myjson = data.rows;
});

$(document).ready(function () {

    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
      pageSize: 10,
      data: myjson,
      autoSync: true,
      schema: {
...